# SVM integer features

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

I'm using the SVM classifier in the machine learning scikit-learn package for python. 
My features are integers. When I call the fit function, I get the user warning "Scaler assumes floating point values as input, got int32", the SVM returns its prediction, I calculate the confusion matrix (I have 2 classes) and the prediction accuracy.
I've tried to avoid the user warning, so I saved the features as floats. Indeed, the warning disappeared, but I got a completely different confusion matrix and prediction accuracy (surprisingly much less accurate)
Does someone know why it happens? What is preferable, should I send the features as float or integers?
Thanks!

Comment: Floats are preferred because integers will be copied/converted into a float array, so you're wasting memory. It's strange that you should get different results, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should convert them as floats but the way to do it depends on what the integer features actually represent.

What is the meaning of your integers? Are they category membership indicators (for instance: 1 == sport, 2 == business, 3 == media, 4 == people...) or numerical measures with an order relationship (3 is larger than 2 that is in turn is larger than 1). You cannot say that "people" is larger than "media" for instance. It is meaningless and would confuse the machine learning algorithm to give it this assumption.

Categorical features should hence be transformed to explode each feature as several boolean features (with value 0.0 or 1.0) for each possible category. Have a look at the [DictVectorizer class](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) in scikit-learn to better understand what I mean by categorical features.

If there are numerical values just convert them as floats and maybe use the Scaler to have them loosely in the range [-1, 1]. If they span several order of magnitudes (e.g. counts of word occurrences) then taking the logarithm of the counts might yield better results. More documentation on feature preprocessing and examples in this section of the documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

**Edit**: also read this guide that has many more details for features representation and preprocessing: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks! My features are numeric measures with an order relationship, in range of 0-9. I've just converted the to float with the float casting. It's quite strange it gives me different results.

Comment: Could you please fill a bug report with a minimalistic reproduction case (python script + data subset) that exhibit the issue on a http://gist.github.com and link in a new issue on http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues ?